# Facebook comments plugin breaks Internet Explorer 7

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-7, facebook-comments

I am using following code after body tag:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and to display comment plugin and like plugin I am using the following code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com/" data-send="true" data-width="450"  data-show-faces="true"></div>
<br /><br />
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/" data-num-posts="5" data-width="470"></div>
```

On Internet Explorer 7 on Windows XP, after a while Internet Explorer crash.
There are also messages that there is problem: "Object does not support this property or method" https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%[.....]&locale=sv_SE&numposts=5&sdk=joey&width=470

How to fix that problem?